# Create a function that computes a tally of all the distinct words appearing in a list of list

Tags: haskell

```
wordCount [] = []
wordCount ([]:xss) = wordCount xss
wordCount ((x:xs):xss) = (x , 1 + length (filter (==x) xs:xss)) : wordCount (xs:xss)
```

So i need to create a function that takes a list of lists that contains strings and returns the count of each word in the list. I created this function however i got two problems, first one is that it does not return the correct count and the second is that it returns duplicates.

```
wordCount [["a", "rose", "is", "a", "rose"],["but", "so", "is", "a", "rose"]]

--> [("a",3),("rose",3),("is",3),("a",3),("rose",3),("but",2),("so",2),("is",2),("a",2),("rose",2)]
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: [("rose", 3), ("a", 3), ("is", 2), ("but", 1), ("so", 1)]

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the lists to get one list, then sort it, group it, and find the lengths of the groups:

```hs
import Data.List

wordCount :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [(a, Int)]
wordCount = map (\x -> (head x, length x)) . group . sort . concat
```

If you can't import things, then you can make `group` and `sort` yourself:

```hs
sort' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
sort' [] = []
sort' (x:xs) = sort' left ++ pivot ++ sort' right
    where
        left = filter (< x) xs
        pivot = x:filter (== x) xs
        right = filter (> x) xs

group' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
group' [] = []
group' [x] = [[x]]
group' (x:xs) =
    if x == head f
        then (x:f):l
        else [x]:rest
    where rest@(f:l) = group' xs

wordCount :: (Ord a) => [[a]] -> [(a, Int)]
wordCount = map (\x -> (head x, length x)) . group' . sort' . concat
```

Comment: forgot to mention that i am not allowed to import anything

Comment: @HasanSaleh I've edited my answer to include a solution without imports.